# How to know if question has serial voting?

Tags: support, serial-voting

I am just confused about [a question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45231474/how-to-receive-affinipay-web-hook-response) which has 5 upvotes only till now and has an accepted answer by the same user. The question does not have much detail about the problem.

I just wanted to know: Are those real or fake upvotes?

Comment: Flag it “in need of moderator intervention” with the explanation above

Comment: @sideshowbarker can you please explain how can i do that? I should write in the question title?

Comment: It's unpossible for regular users to know, but if you suspect there's something shady going on you can always post a moderator flag where you explain why you think something is wrong. 5 upvotes and 41 views for a question like that is not normal.

Comment: The flagging dialog is available when you click on the gray link that says *"flag"*, right under the question tags. Posting here can also help of course, but if everyone did that the front page of meta would be very busy :)

Comment: @ivarni how can i get the attention of  moderator? the question got 41 views just because of my question. Before posting this there were only 30+ views.

Comment: After looking at that question, I’m now wondering why you even care. The question was created 2017-07-21 (almost 6 months ago) and the questioner answered it only today, just a few minutes before you posted here. And it has a deleted (non)answer saying, *“Having same problem. If you find out tell me too”*. So it doesn’t seem terrifically surprising it gathered a few upvotes over the last six months.

Comment: @sideshowbarker that question was just came up on the front page, so i just checked that.

Comment: I'm curious to know why you're asking about a question that happened 6+ months ago. Where did you get that reference from?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

"Serial upvoting" refers to large numbers of votes from User A to User B. A user can only vote once on any given post. This means that what you're describing (5 upvotes on a particular post) could not possibly be a serial voting problem.

There's no other fishy behavior going on, either.

In the future, if you want to alert people to a potential problem like this, please use a flag on the post.

Comment: Worth noting, getting a bunch of upvotes onto the same post could be an example of sockpuppets (inter-account voting fraud) instead of serial voting.  Not saying that's the case here, but it's helpful terminology.

Comment: @ryanyuyu Fair point.

Comment: @EdCottrell Do you also have a tool to detect these sockpuppets votes ?

Comment: @AntoinePelletier All I can say is that we have tools for detecting a range of voting (and other) abuses, and we are very good at catching people who run sockpuppets.

Answer (score 5):

By looking at the [post history](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/45231474/timeline), it looks like the question got 4 up-votes on the day of submission and then again once more about 2 months later.

Doesn't look like anything fishy to me. Posts always get more attention the first few minutes after submission. Had those votes happened now (half a year later) it would definitely be a bit fishy, but that's not the case here.